# URL used to deploy ipa with Enterprise Certificate

Tags: ios, deployment

I have an Apple Enterprise Certificate and want to deploy my app wirelessly to testers. Of course, I need to specify a URL of my ipa file. My question is, is any url OK?

Currently I put my ipa in the Amazon S3 server, and made a simple website with a link

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/test.plist" id="text">
```

When you open my website on your iPhone, you can easily install my app by a tap.

However, my concern is, since the URL is public (you can download the plist file, open it with a text editor, and see the URL of the ipa file), and anyone who have the URL can download it, is there any potential danger?

Answer (score 0):

[From Apple's support center:](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)

> The iOS Developer Enterprise Program only allows you to distribute
>   your apps to employees or members of your organization through Ad Hoc
>   distribution

As far as I understand from enterprise license legal agreements, you must care about security by yourself. The link on ipa file is intended only for your employees and you mustn't make it public.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a sort of redirection management of your url in relation to a session login parameters...
Anyhow I agree with @Alex Peda