# Configuring HTTPS access in Amazon Web Service SS3 bucket for iOS Application Adhoc

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to setup my own iOS IPA beta distribution service using my website hosted on Amazon Web Service (AWS) with S3 for the files, and Route53 to point the urls.

I followed the CloudFront CloudFront Private Content Getting Started page, in order to create the links mentioned in the code below.

I have a bucket (beta.myurl.com) which holds three files - .plist, .html (to supply info and download link to ipa), and the .ipa itself (with the ad-hoc certificate integrated inside of it).

Apple requires these files to be distributed via HTTPS if to be able to visit and install straight from the phone.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

index.html link

```
<div class="link"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=
https://beta.trentrand.com.s3.amazonaws.com/manifest.plist?AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY&Expires=1407715664&Signature=MYSIGNATURE">
Tap Here to Install<br />MY APP 2.1 (2.1)<br />Directly On Your Device</a></div>
```

inside my .plist is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://beta.trentrand.com.s3.amazonaws.com/MY%20APP.ipa?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEYID&amp;Expires=EXPIRES&amp;Signature=SIGNATURE</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.Package.Name</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0 (1.0)</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>MY APP</string>
           </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then of course, my .ipa is the folder as 'MY APP.ipa'

Does anyone know why it is not working properly from my phone?

When I click the download link it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

even when i am a little late ;) [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704552/url-used-to-deploy-ipa-with-enterprise-certificate) is somebody who made it, your .plist looks ok.

Comment: Thanks for this! Fortunately, I can now use TestFlight instead of this.